# Android:java runtime exception unable to create service

Tags: android

i have created a project which uses a class called service class to get location continously and save it to an array list. But its showing some errors. The project is on android 2.1

Serviceclass.java

```
package com.example.tracemeendpointsjson;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import Trace.date.TimeDate;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ServiceClass  extends Service implements LocationListener {
    double mLongitude ;
    double mLatitude;
    boolean check;
    public static int k;
    CommonClass cmn;
    MainActivity ma;
    int i;
    LocationManager mLocationManager;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(ServiceClass.this, "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        cmn=new CommonClass();
        ma=new MainActivity();

        cmn.StartTime=new TimeDate().timeToString();
         System.out.println("StartTime ::  "+cmn.StartTime);
         cmn.StartDate=new TimeDate().dateToString();
         System.out.println("StartDate ::  "+cmn.StartDate);



        check = true;
        i = 0;
        k=0;
        initializeLocationAndStartGpsThread();


    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setCurrentGpsLocation(location);    
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }





    private void setCurrentGpsLocation(Location location) {
        String bestProvider = "";
        if (location == null) {

            mLocationManager =(LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this); // Every 10000 msecs  
                    System.out.println("GPS_PROVIDER:  ");
            location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);             

        }
        try {
            mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
         mLatitude = location.getLatitude();

         String la=Double.toString(mLatitude);
         String ln=Double.toString(mLongitude);

         System.out.println("B  4 Size  ::  "+cmn.Lat.size());
         System.out.println("B  4 array  ::  "+cmn.Lat);
         cmn.Lat.add(la);
         cmn.Long.add(ln);
         System.out.println("after size  ::  "+cmn.Lat.size());
         System.out.println("after array  ::  "+cmn.Lat);


         String UpdatedTime=new TimeDate().timeToString();
         cmn.TimeArray.add(UpdatedTime);
         System.out.println("UpdatedTime  ::  "+UpdatedTime);
         System.out.println("cmn.TimeArray  ::  "+cmn.TimeArray.size());
         System.out.println("cmn.TimeArray  ::  "+cmn.TimeArray);

         String UpdatedDate=new TimeDate().dateToString();
         cmn.DateArray.add(UpdatedDate);
         System.out.println("UpdatedDate  ::  "+UpdatedDate);
         System.out.println("cmn.DateArray  ::  "+cmn.DateArray.size());
         System.out.println("cmn.DateArray  ::  "+cmn.DateArray);


         k++;

//          Log.i("hai01", "<long,lat> = <" + mLongitude + "," + mLatitude);
//          System.out.println("LOgGgggggggggggg");
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            msg.what = 1;
            ServiceClass.this.updateHandler.sendMessage(msg);

            String cityName = null;  
            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(ServiceClass.this, Locale.ENGLISH);  

            List<Address> addresses=null;  
            try {  
             addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(mLongitude, mLatitude, 1);  

             if (addresses.size() > 0)  

              System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());  
             cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();  
            } catch (IOException e) {  
             e.printStackTrace();  
            }  



            String s = ln + "\n" + la  
              + "\n\nMy Current City is: " + cityName;  
            Toast.makeText(ServiceClass.this, "City is:"+s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.i("hai02", "Null pointer exception ");
        }
     }



    Handler updateHandler = new Handler() {
        /** Gets called on every message that is received */
        // @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case 1: {
                Log.i("hai03", "Updated location = " + mLatitude + " " + mLongitude);
                break;
            }
            case 0: {
                Log.i("hai000000000000", "Running");
                break;
            }
                }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
     };








     private void initializeLocationAndStartGpsThread() {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            List<String> providers = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);
            Log.i("hai04", "Enabled providers = " + providers.toString());
            String provider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(),true);
            Log.i("hai05", "Best provider = " + provider);

            //setCurrentGpsLocation(null);   

         }




     @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            check = false;
            i = 0;


           cmn.Lat.clear();
           cmn.Long.clear();
           cmn.FinalDistance.clear();
           ma.finaldist=0.0f;
           cmn.TimeArray.clear();
           cmn.DateArray.clear();


           System.out.println("Clear size  ::  "+cmn.Lat);
           System.out.println("Clear size  ::  "+cmn.Long);
           System.out.println("Clear size  ::  "+cmn.Lat.size());
           System.out.println("Clear size  ::  "+cmn.Long.size());
            Toast.makeText(ServiceClass.this, "Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

}
```

Logcat output is:

```
04-10 22:55:50.318: E/AndroidRuntime(249): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-10 22:55:50.361: E/AndroidRuntime(249): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.example.tracemeendpointsjson.ServiceClass: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid location 0, size is 0
04-10 22:55:50.361: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2790)
04-10 22:55:50.361: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:119)
04-10 22:55:50.361: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1917)
04-10 22:55:50.361: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 22:55:50.361: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-10 22:55:50.361: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-10 22:55:50.361: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 22:55:50.361: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-10 22:55:50.361: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-10 22:55:50.361: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-10 22:55:50.361: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 22:55:50.361: E/AndroidRuntime(249): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid location 0, size is 0
04-10 22:55:50.361: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:341)
04-10 22:55:50.361: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at com.example.tracemeendpointsjson.ServiceClass.setCurrentGpsLocation(ServiceClass.java:143)
04-10 22:55:50.361: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at com.example.tracemeendpointsjson.ServiceClass.initializeLocationAndStartGpsThread(ServiceClass.java:193)
04-10 22:55:50.361: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at com.example.tracemeendpointsjson.ServiceClass.onCreate(ServiceClass.java:55)
04-10 22:55:50.361: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2780)
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your culprit:

```
04-10 22:55:50.361: E/AndroidRuntime(249): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid location 0, size is 0
04-10 22:55:50.361: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at com.example.tracemeendpointsjson.ServiceClass.setCurrentGpsLocation(ServiceClass.java:143)
```

in ServiceClass.java line 143 you are reaching out of bounds of your array, hence the exception that leads your app to crash. And this is all because you got bad habit of not putting conditional blocks in brackets, so you have

```
if (addresses.size() > 0)  
System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());  
cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
```

while you should

```
if (addresses.size() > 0)  {
    System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());  
    cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();  
}
```